# Awk, order foreach 12 lines to insert query

Tags: sql, perl, awk, sed, jq

I have the following script:

```
curl -s 'https://someonepage=5m' | jq '.[]|.[0],.[1],.[2],.[3],.[4],.[5],.[6],.[7],.[8],.[9],.[10],.[11],.[12]' | perl -p -e 's/\"//g' |awk '/^[0-9]/{print; if (++onr%12 == 0) print ""; }'
```

This is part of result:

```
1517773500000
0.10250100
0.10275700
0.10243500
0.10256600
257.26700000
1517773799999
26.38912220
1229
104.32200000
10.70579910
0

1517773800000
0.10256600
0.10268000
0.10231600
0.10243400
310.64600000
1517774099999
31.83806883
1452
129.70500000
13.29758266
0

1517774100000
0.10243400
0.10257500
0.10211800
0.10230000
359.06300000
1517774399999
36.73708621
1296
154.78500000
15.84041910
0
```

I want to insert this data in a MySQL database. I want for each line this result:

```
(1517773800000,0.10256600,0.10268000,0.10231600,0.10243400,310.64600000,1517774099999,31.83806883,1452,129.70500000,13.29758266,0)

(1517774100000,0.10243400,0.10257500,0.10211800,0.10230000,359.06300000,151774399999,36.73708621,1296,154.78500000,15.84041910,0)
```

I need merge lines each 12 lines, any can help me for get this result.

Comment: You'd probably be better off doing everything in jq.  Could you please post a sample of the input in accordance with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi @peak, this is the sample: [link] https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=ETHBTC&interval=5m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an all-jq solution:

```
.[] | .[0:12] | @tsv | gsub("\t";",") | "(\(.))"
```

In the sample, all the subarrays have length 12, so you might be able to drop the `.[0:12]` part of the pipeline. If using jq 1.5 or later, you could use `join(“,”)` instead of the @tsv|gsub portion of the pipeline. You might, for example, want to consider:

```
.[] | join(“,”) | “(\(.))”.   # jq 1.5 or later
```

Invocation: use the -r command-line option

Sample output:

```
(1517627400000,0.10452300,0.10499000,0.10418200,0.10449400,819.50400000,1517627699999,85.57150693,2340,452.63400000,47.27213035,0)
(1517627700000,0.10435700,0.10449200,0.10366000,0.10370000,717.37000000,1517627999999,74.60582079,1996,321.25500000,33.42273846,0)
(1517628000000,0.10376600,0.10390000,0.10366000,0.10370400,519.59400000,1517628299999,53.88836170,1258,239.89300000,24.88613854,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=""; OFS=","} {$1=$1; $0="("$0")"}1' file
(1517773500000,0.10250100,0.10275700,0.10243500,0.10256600,257.26700000,1517773799999,26.38912220,1229,104.32200000,10.70579910,0)
(1517773800000,0.10256600,0.10268000,0.10231600,0.10243400,310.64600000,1517774099999,31.83806883,1452,129.70500000,13.29758266,0)
(1517774100000,0.10243400,0.10257500,0.10211800,0.10230000,359.06300000,1517774399999,36.73708621,1296,154.78500000,15.84041910,0)
```

**RS=""**:
Treat groups of lines separated one or more blank lines as a record

**OFS=","**
Set the output separator to be a ","

**$1=$1**
Reconstitute the line, replacing the input separators with the output separator

**$0="("$0")"**
Surround the record with parens

**1**
Print the record

Comment: Thank you jas, its work, i solved with jq solution of @peak.

Comment: Great. I agree that the jq solution is the better option in this case.